# C Program: Update unsigned char pointer array with function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, unsigned-char

I have a function to update an `unsigned char*` and cannot find where my bug is. I'm not sure if I need to allocate memory, or if I am pointing to the wrong memory space somewhere. I tried to follow a similar structure as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611832/changing-an-array-with-a-function-in-c), but have not had success with an `unsigned char`.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeArray(unsigned char **arr)
{
    unsigned char ptr[3] = {100, 101, 102};
    *arr = ptr;
    printf("%d\n", **(arr+0)); // This prints out the correct value of 100
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char *blah;
    unsigned char ptr2[3] = {103, 104, 105};
    blah = ptr2;
    printf("Blah is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d,",*(blah+i)); //This prints out 103,104,105
    }
    changeArray(&blah);
    printf("Blah is now: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d,", *(blah +i)); //This prints out 0,0,0
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help in determining how to properly access the values set in the changeArray() function would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this `*arr = ptr;` you are storing a pointer to a variable with *automatic storage duration*. The behaviour [*undefined*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can dynamically allocate and return a pointer that way:

```
void changeArray(unsigned char **arr)
{
    unsigned char ptr[3] = {100, 101, 102};
    unsigned char *p = malloc(sizeof ptr); 
    memcpy(p, ptr, sizeof ptr);
    *arr = p;
    printf("%d\n", **(arr+0)); // This prints out the correct value of 100
}
```

You should also do error checking if `malloc` failed and remember to `free` the allocated memory after use in `main`.

Comment: Sir, if i'm not wrong, passing `blah` itself will do the job, pointer to pointer is not necessary. Can you please review my answer once for correctness?

Comment: It depends. I did the way I did because OP passes a `&blah` and updating the pointer with `*arr=ptr;`, which is typically how pointer is updated. The way you did will modify the array `ptr2`. So that's also fine if OP wanted to modify the array `ptr2`.

Comment: Sir, based on the usage of the _modified_ array, I came to my conclusion that it's only the values that matter to OP, that's why I suggested so. Your approach is also absolutely correct also, no doubts. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, `ptr` is local to `changeArray()` function. So once the function finishes execution, there is no existance of `ptr`. Hence, once you assign `ptr` to `*arr`

```
*arr = ptr;
```

and `changeArray()` execution gets over, accessing `blah` in `main()` now will invoke  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, you don't need to pass the address of `blah`, you don't need a pointer-to-pointer at all. `blah` is already a pointer, which you can pass to `changeArray()` to alter the contents of the memory area it points to. You can do something like

```
void changeArray(unsigned char *arr)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        arr[i] = 100+i;
}
```

and call it like

```
changeArray(blah);
```